# Import a package in Android but not in IOS for a Flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to add in a PDF viewer for a flutter app I'm building, but I'm stuck at an error that is thrown for the iOS build for importing a package that doesn't support iOS.

I would like to import and use this package for building the app for Android and use another package for iOS and I was wondering if this is possible and if so, how I can achieve that.

Comment: I had the exact same issue with the package, I couldn't find a way of restricting packages to builds unfortunately. I moved to a different pdf package called flutter_pdfview https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible I'm afraid.

Your issue sounds like the same problem I had with Flutter PDF Viewer package. I found another package which works perfectly for me and does all the things I needed, hopefully it is suitable for your needs too. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview

Answer (score -1):

Probably possible

use Platform

```
import 'dart:io';
Platform.isIOS // Returns true on iOS devices
Platform.isAndroid // Returns true on Android devices
```

Comment: It's a build problem, so the issue is pubspec's package import.

Comment: oh... ok ;(  my mistake